# obj-C/Cocoa passing parameters of unknown class (but common parentage) to method. Possible?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, class, methods

I have a collection of classes defined from UIView.

```
@interface {

UIView *thisView
UIView *thatView

}
```

...

```
thisView *viewOne = [[thisView alloc] init];
thatView *viewTwo = [[thatView alloc] init];
```

Now, say I want to create a method that will take these objects and call a function that is common to them both and also set common parameters and do all kinds of unbeknownst things, how do I pass these objects on to it if they are of different classes (assuming they are quite dissimilar)?

```
[self exampleMethod:viewOne];
[self exampleMethod:viewTwo];

- (void)exampleMethod:(UIView *)viewNumber //will this suffice?
{
    [viewNumber anotherMethod];
```

...

Comment: Your code isn't valid Objective-C... can you clean it up so that it makes some more sense?

Comment: If by 'parentage' you mean both objects share the same super class, why don't you make your method take objects of that class instead of `UIView`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two most common practices are:

1. Make a `UIView` subclass (`exampleClass`) that contains all the "things in common" – methods, properties, etc. – and then define your `thisView` and `thatView` classes as subclasses of `exampleClass`. You can then use `exampleClass` as the parameter in your `exampleMethod`.
2. Create a [protocol](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocProtocols.html), and then have `thisView` and `thatView` implement the protocol.

Both of these techniques are fundamental to Objective-C (and to object-oriented programming), and it's probably worth learning more about them before you invest a lot of time writing code.

Answer (score 1):

If there is a common parent class that responds to the messages you're planning to send, you can type the variable as that. Otherwise, you can create a protocol that specifies the common interface.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to use generic objects you can check to see if they respond to the message you want to perform. Then perform the message.

```
id blah;

if ([blah respondsToSelector:@selector(someMethod:)])
{
    [blah performSelector:@selector(someMethod:) withObject:anObject];
}
```

for your example

```
- (void)exampleMethod:(UIView *)viewNumber //will this suffice?
{
    if ([viewNumber respondsToSelector:@selector(anotherMethod)])
    {
        [viewNumber performSelector:@selector(anotherMethod)];
    }

}
```